# mobile hotspot connection fails on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lts

Good day,
I am a new ubuntu user and I've been searching for a solution everywhere to this issue:
I run ubuntu (studio) 16.04 lts, code name: xenial dual booted with windows 8 on Hp notebook 15. When I first installed ubuntu, hotspot from my BlackBerry q10, it connects fine to the hotspot but suddenly it stopped and every time i connect it pops up the dialog box: wifi authentication required by wifi network and expects me to retype a password that is already correct! It connects to others by the way.
What do you think I should do?